# How to show use ng-repeat to show model values

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I can't figure out how to connect my model with my angular view in ASP.net MVC. I am trying to show the FirstName and LastName values from the User model.
Here is my view:

```
<table class="table" ng-app="UserApp" style="background: white;" height="1200">
<tbody ng-controller="SearchController">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in User">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ user.FirstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    private GigDB db = new GigDB();
    // GET: Search
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        List<User> users;

        users = db.Users.ToList();

        return View(users);

    }
}
```

Here is the model:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Lastly, the script:

```
var app = angular.module('UserApp', []);
app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    console.log($scope.model);
    console.log($scope.model[0].FirstName);

});
```

What I am confused about, is the console.log in the script is working and shows the user objects correctly with all of the values. Also when I console.log @scope.model[0], that pulls the value correctly as well but in the angular view I cannot get the values to show at all.

Comment: You did `$scope.model = ...`, so shouldn't you iterate over `model` instead of `User` in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Shouldn't `<tr ng-repeat="user in User">` be `<tr ng-repeat="user in model">`? You never declare a `User` property in your scope

Comment: That is what I originally tried and I just realized the way the table was laid out, I was actually getting the values that way but it was off the screen and I couldn't see it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code C# like this to return Json object

```
 public JsonResult Search()
{
    List<User> users;

    users = db.Users.ToList();

    return JSon(users,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and script should like this to call data:

```
app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope) {
 $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/SearchController/Search'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
              $scope.User= response.data;
            });
```

});

It may help you

Answer (score -1):

So, originally in my view I had:

```
<table class="table" ng-app="UserApp" style="background: white;" height="1200">
<tbody ng-controller="SearchController">
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="user in model"> //model here instead of User..
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ user.FirstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
}
```

and I thought that it was not working, but as it turns out the table just stretched far down on the screen and I couldn't see the values being shown. Oops.